# What factors influence the resolution that a monitor can use?

Tags: display, graphics-card, resolution, lcd

Let me explain what I'm asking. First of all it's my understanding that native resolution means the same thing as maximum resolution in the context of LCD monitors (is this correct?). If a monitor has native resolution of `A x B` does that mean it can feasibly support any resolution `C x D` where `C < A` and `D < B` and `A/B` = `C/D`. For example if a monitor supports `1920 x 1080` then must it support `1680 x 1050`? Why are there situations where 30" monitors with native `2560 x 1600` can do only `1280 x 800` even though the video card can most certainly support `1280 x 1024` is it because the ratio between the two numbers is different?

Comment: Something that can artificially limit the resolution a monitor will accept will be the cable between the graphics card and monitor.  If you have a single link DVI cable then you will be limited to resolutions below 1920 x 1080. http://superuser.com/questions/326554/lg-w3000h-native-resolution/326559#326559

Answer (score 0):

The factors that determine the res that a monitor uses is the display engine put in to "drive the pannel".
You should be able to derive this information from the specs, or the manuel, and when all else fails the "monitor driver" (profile) for that monitor.

Native does not always mean maximum, there have existed monitors that have a native resolution that is smaller than the total resolution that the processing engine can process/interpolate.   There are are a few computer monitor and projectors that will do that.
 A nice example and quite common is a 1280x720 television easily accepting a 1920x1080 (larger) input to be interpolated (in the processing engine) to the max res of the 720 pannel it is displayed to.

If your not getting modes visable , that it is possible for the monitor to display, then it is possible that would change when installing the monitor profile. (so called monitor driver)
Also  depending on the software for the GPU item your using, there are a lot of switches, and buttons in there that can change things around. "List All Modes" in windows systems could make visable modes that may or may not work.  HDMI outputs often have thier own adjustment things available in the gpu software.

If it is very high resolutions (above 1920x1200) you are trying to achieve and they are not working correctaly, you will have to make sure that you have Dual Link output , and cables that support the dual link , to get the bandwidth nessisary to work in that resolution.

For ages now, manufacturing of monitors even back in CRT days, it has been common to have some resolutions that the processing engine works easily with, to maintain aspect ratio, and allow for variations. But usually there was some limitations to what they take as an input, even if that would have meant it was not using the whole screen, they just did not take it.

Conclusion:
 Yes monitors can support various smaller reses usually, Larger reses sometimes, but there is nothing that requires them to do so, it is all in what they wish to implement. It probably would be easier to read what it does work with, then to guess and test each one.

Side notes: Omni-Sync crt monitors tried to support a vast array of resolutions and sync rates and all, they were more expencive and not many were made (compared to multi-sync).